# How to use one object color as a factor for another objects color/glare?

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, color, compositing-nodes

I have an object with wave gradient texture. Above it, I put many balls, some of them touch the first object. I want to make color of the balls to be different depending if the ball touches green or white area. Or to make balls glare if they touch green area.

How should I set the balls material to achieve this? Or should it be done in compositing?
[image]

Comment: Is this static? Or are the balls moving?

Comment: It is a static image. In eevee engine.